# How to format date receiving through Vuejs Datepicker in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datepicker, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I'm building an application in `Vuejs` with `Laravel` as backend. I'm using `datepicker` to add dates in column. I'm getting an error of

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-05-04T18:30:00.000Z' for column 'schedule' at row 1

I'm sending the date in request:

[image]

And while doing dd in laravel I'm getting:

[image]

Can someone guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to parse the date and format it accordingly

```
$mydate = '2017-05-04T18:30:00.000Z'; // $request->schedule

$parsed_date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($mydate)->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change your request date format by using `moment(this.schedule).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')`. Then in server you could parse easily with `new(Carbon(request('schedule'));`