# A two digit month could not be found Data missing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

I'm having a table where I'm storing the data in date format through datepicker. While storing the date I'm doing something like this:

```
$data['schedule'] = Carbon::parse($request->schedule)->toDateTimeString();
```

then in model I've defined like following:

```
protected $dates = [
    'schedule', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'
];
```

Now while retrieving the date I'm using `diffForHumans()` something like this:

```
$event->schedule = $event->schedule->diffForHumans();
```

But it is throwing an error like this:

> A two digit month could not be found. Data missing

I checked mySQL database for the format , I'm having dates like this:

```
2017-07-02 14:38:23
```

**Edit:**

Previously I was having an issue while storing the date in tables, please refer to [How to format date receiving through Vuejs Datepicker in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275671/how-to-format-date-receiving-through-vuejs-datepicker-in-laravel) for the detailed description. It throws error of:

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2017-05-04T18:30:00.000Z' for column 'schedule' at row 1

So I chose to use `Carbon::parse` while storing it in database.

How to resolve this, help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is you are already changing the format before in $data['schedule'] comment it out and check

Comment: @Exprator If I don't use `Carbon::parse...` then it is not accepting values in table

Comment: What do you get if you do `dd($request->schedule);` before `$data['schedule']`?

Comment: ok so you need to format the datetime while its being accessed in the carbon, like the format you have in the database

Comment: @Exprator Yes you can say I'm looking for accessor.

Comment: i guess you can pass the format in the toDateTimeString or diffForHumans to format it according to your need. get through the documentation i guess it will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with an accessor method in your model.

```
public function getScheduleAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->diffForHumans();
}
```

and access the attribute as

```
$event->schedule;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set datetime format ('Y-m-d H:i:s')

and run

Comment: You mean as mutator?

Comment: Yes @NitishKumar
Its helping you or not?